# How to set the row and column using fontWithName: matrix: method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to set the row and column using `fontWithName:matrix:` method?

```
float myMatrix[16, 32];

NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Courier" matrix: myMatrix];
```

I tried doing as above, but didn't get the output. Or is there any other class or method to do this? Please find me the right solution.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Does your code even compile? The first line doesn't look like it would. The matrix should be a transformation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Despite being called a “matrix”, the array expected by `fontWithName:matrix:` is simply a flat array; it is not an array of arrays (a “two-dimensional array”).

[The documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFont/fontWithName%3amatrix%3a):

> The `fontMatrix` is a standard 6-element transformation matrix as used in the PostScript language, specifically with the `makefont` operator. In most cases, you can simply use `fontWithName:size:` to create standard scaled fonts.
>
> You can use the defined value `NSFontIdentityMatrix` for `[1 0 0 1 0 0]`. Fonts created with a matrix other than `NSFontIdentityMatrix` don’t automatically flip themselves in flipped views.

So, you need to pass a single flat array of six `CGFloat`s. (They should not be `float`s unless you're using a *really* old version of Xcode.)

Exactly which six numbers they need to be, only you can determine, since you're the only one who knows the significance of “16” and “32” in the code you showed in the question.